# facebook share dialog gets cropped

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

The problem is that my like button is quite at the bottom at the page,

And when someone clicks the like button, the dialog just gets cropped,

and I just can't do anything with it.

Did anyone have a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: The google +1 button just works perfectly, and the dialog actually comes upwards. I wonder if it's possible to make something similar with facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix this is by using some CSS to your page to move the dialog box.  This is kind of a hack, but its the only way to really do what you want.  The only downside is that the tiny triangle in the top left corner of the dialog will seem out of place.

One other option that does not involve moving the dialog is to make your page slightly longer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ideas,well I tried to hack it to put upstairs but it wouldn't work that ways since its tied up in iframe, or it would be messy like hell.
The only solution I found working, is to actually put these like above the comments. Just like they do on the blogs.